# ASP.net / VB.net / SQL Server : change variables without page request

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, windows

I'm stuck with building my own, simple browser game.

My program: you can upgrade your tools which allow you to gain more points per hour.

My problem:

So for example a user logs in and upgrades his tools from 0 to 1 which would double the amount of points gained. But upgrading takes 2 hours to complete. I don't expect my user to be online for 2 hours so I save the time he was last seen in an SQL table. Now when 2 hours have passed the amount of points gained need to be doubled but it's very possible that the user doesn't visit the page for another 10 hours. So my current program keeps adding 1 point per hour until the user visits the page. So in this case he'd have 12 points. But it needs to multiply after 2 hours so he needs to have 22 points.

Another, maybe simpler example is a maximum amount of points. Let's say the max is 10 points. But the user stays offline for 15 hours which means he'd earn 15 points at a rate of 1pnt/hr.

I don't have any functionally code yet because I want to know if something like this is actually possible and how for example cityVille(facebook) does it.

Now my question:

Can anyone give me a tip or give me some info on how to get started at this or at least give me the name of what I'm searching for? I've tried google'ing things like "offline database interactions" or "changing variables without user request" but nothing useful comes up.

Thanks in advance,

BlaDrzz.

Comment: What do you mean by "upgrading takes two hours to complete"? Does this mean that the code to process the update takes two hours or processing time before it finishes, or that there is a rule in your game that says the upgrade points do not take effect for 2 hrs ?

Comment: It takes 2 hours to upgrade the tools but you will still recieve points when it's upgrading. So let's say you earn 1 point/hour then you'd have 2 points when the upgrading is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule jobs with SQL server. These jobs can run at whatever frequency you like.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Comment: Is it possible for a "not too expensive server" to run thousands of these jobs at once? Because if there are 200 people playing and they're all constantly upgrading then this can cause lag?